# Is there a publicly accessible bamboo instance running anywhere?

Tags: continuous-integration, bamboo

I'm looking for a publicly accessible bamboo instance, preferably an official Atlassian one, and preferably building some realistic projects.

I think one used to exist at http://opensource.bamboo.atlassian.com -- or so say the [Atlassian Forums](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?messageID=257244300�) -- but it appears to be dead now. Any others out there?

Comment: Just adding my two cents worth, but if you're evaluating whether or not to use it, we paid for consultants and spent two months going round and round with Bamboo, and then gave up.  We then tried CruiseControl.net (free) and got it up and running correctly without help in about a day.  Bamboo is probably perfecly good software, but from my experience, the (free) CruiseControl.NET software is better.  I would imagine CruiseControl (the original version) is just as good if not better.

Comment: I'm not evaluating whether or not to use it. I just need to play with its REST APIs in a public forum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also posted this question on the [Atlassian Forums](http://forums.atlassian.com/thread.jspa?threadID=54760) and got an answer there. Here's the gist:

Some Atlassian projects (smaller ones, like libraries) use instances that can be accessed. One such instance can be found [here](https://studio.plugins.atlassian.com/builds/allPlans.action).

Furthermore, Atlassian supports open source/non-profit projects by issuing [free licences](http://www.atlassian.com/software/bamboo/licensing.jsp#nonprofit). Projects making use of such licenses to host publicly facing Bamboo instances can be found by performing an appropriately constructed google search. Here are some examples:

- [Publicly accessible Bamboo instances in a recent version](http://www.google.com/search?q=dashboard%20%22powered%20by%20Atlassian%20Bamboo%20version%203.1.1%22)
- [Publicly accessible Bamboo instances of open source projects](http://www.google.com/search?q=Powered%20by%20a%20free%20Atlassian%20Bamboo%20open%20source%20license%20dashboard)
- [All Bamboo instances used by open source projects](http://www.google.com/search?q=Powered%20by%20a%20free%20Atlassian%20Bamboo%20open%20source%20license)